# Geom_density plot in R for percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I made a plot with ages on the x-axis and frequencies on the y-axis. The lines are plotted for 5 different years (2017 till 2021).
[image]

This was my R-code:

```
ggplot(Ingrepen9, aes(LeeftijdBijOK, stat(count), cut=Operatiejaar, colour=Operatiejaar)) +
geom_density(show.legend=TRUE) +
ggtitle(
  label = "Verdeling leeftijden van patiënten",
  subtitle = "Absolute aantallen uit het WKZ") +
theme(
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
xlab("Leeftijd bij operatie") +
ylab("Frequentie") +
xlim(0, 60) +
scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Instead of absolute frequencies, I want to make this picture with percentages on the y-axis. Because every year, there is a different total of operations, so this curves are not really usable to compare the different years.

But how to do that? I tried different codes and searched on the internet, but I could not find the answere...

For example, I first calculated the percentages:

```
Ingrepen9.1 <- Ingrepen9.1 %>%
group_by(Operatiejaar, LeeftijdBijOK) %>%
summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
mutate(Percentage = formattable::percent(cnt / sum(cnt)))
```

And then I tried to plot the Percentages instead of the count, but that did not work...

Comment: Can you provide all/some of your data using `dput(Ingrepen9)` or `dput(head(Ingrepen9, n = 20))`, depending on the size of your dataset? Your post isn't currently reproducible.

Comment: If you add the argument `stat = "scaled"` to `geom_density`, you should get normalized values on the y-axis. See `?geom_density`.